# Prove that the equation has at least one solution in an interval, using Lagrange theorem

Tags: calculus

Prove that the equation has at least one solution, in interval $x \in [ \frac{1}{ \sqrt[]{3} }, \sqrt[]{3}]$

$$ \frac{1-2x\arctan(x)}{(1+x^2)^2} = - \frac{\pi\sqrt3}{48}$$

I am stumped by this assignment.

I understand Lagrange theorem.

If the function $f(x)$ is defined for every $x \in [a,b]$ and differentiable for every $x \in (a,b)$, then $ \exists c \in (a,b)$, such that $$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$$

What I tried:

$$f(x)=\frac{1-2x\arctan(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}$$ which is obviously defined and differentiable for $x \in [ \frac{1}{ \sqrt[]{3} }, \sqrt[]{3}]$ and $x \in ( \frac{1}{ \sqrt[]{3} }, \sqrt[]{3})$ respectively.

I plugged the function and values in Lagrange theorem formula and got $$\frac{f(\sqrt3) - f(\frac{1}{\sqrt3})}{\sqrt3-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}=-\frac{24\sqrt3-3\pi}{96}$$ I hope that I am not wrong.

The equation above gives us the value of $f'(x)$ in some point $c\in (\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\sqrt3)$, but how can that bring us closer to the solution?

Please, give me a detailed answer and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{\arctan (x)}{1+x^2}\implies f'(x)=\left(\frac{\arctan (x)}{1+x^2}\right)'= \frac{1-2x\arctan(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

Now you need to apply Lagrange theorem to $f(x)$ in the given interval.
 Since $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable in the given interval, 
\begin{align}
&\implies  \frac{f(\sqrt 3)-f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right)}{\sqrt 3-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}}=f'(c)\\
&\implies -\frac{\pi\sqrt3}{48}=f'(c)\\
&\implies \exists c \in \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt 3},\sqrt 3 \right ) \, : \frac{1-2c\arctan(c)}{(1+c^2)^2}= -\frac{\pi\sqrt3}{48}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Just wow... And here I am, expecting a ton of work for the solution. So elegant. Thank you, kind Sir.

Comment: @Shocky2 Welcome Friend, I am glad I could help you! :) And please don't call me Sir, it feels strange to be a Sir when you're 16. Everyone is each other's friend here. :)

Comment: 16? Wow... I wish I knew what arctan actually was when I was 16... Keep up the good work! I was now able to solve a bunch of similar problems using that method... Never occurred to me to integrate the function.